# How can i make this program work?

Tags: c

I will just explain how the program should work. The program will ask you about your weight and then on what planet would you like to be on. After that it should tell you how much you would weigh on that planet. Can anyone give me some hints how to make it work. And is there any way print out the word and the number value that it has. For example Fox = 12 and then print out the value 12 and the word Fox.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>



int main()
{
    float merkuur=0.378, veenus=0.907, maa=1, marss=0.377, jupiter=2.364, saturn=1.064, uraan=0.889, neptuun=1.125, K, X;
    char P;
    printf("Enter your weight:");
    scanf("%f", &K);
    printf("Enter planet (merkuur, veenus, maa, marss, jupiter, saturn, uraan, neptuun):");
    scanf("%s", &P);
    X = P*K;
    printf("Your weight on the planet %.2s would be %s.2f kilograms\n",P,X);
    system ("pause");

}
```

Comment: The line `printf("Enter your weight:");` should be `printf("Enter your mass:");`

Comment: You need to study the basics of arrays, pointers and strings before you'll be able to write this program.

Comment: You need to treat P as a string instead of a Char

Comment: Multiple issues: 1) `char P` can only store 1 character, not an entire string. Either change your `scanf` to accept a `%c`, or change `char P;` to `char P[8]`. 2) `X = P*K;` You're multiplying a `char` and a `float`, what are you expecting to happen here? 3) In your `printf`, again `P` is a single `char`

Comment: Hint: variable names are for the compiler. When the program runs, they don't exist anymore. So at runtime the relation between what the user typed and your gravity constants does not exist. You need a way to do that. In c++ you could use an std::map. In C ... well that's the point of this exercise, no?

Comment: Go talk to your teacher. It seems like you are not understanding basic concepts.

Comment: @RPGillespie I don't have a teacher :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should use something like an associative array.
- You have to allocate enough memory to store the name.

Sample implementation in a straightforward way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct elem_t {
        char name[32];
        float multiplier;
    } table[] = {{"merkuur", 0.378}, {"veenus", 0.907}, {"maa", 1}, {"marss", 0.377}, {"jupiter", 2.364}, {"saturn", 1.064}, {"uraan", 0.889}, {"neptuun", 1.125}, {"", -1}};
    float K, X;
    int i;
    char P[32];
    printf("Enter your weight:");
    if (scanf("%f", &K) != 1)
    {
        puts("input error");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter planet (merkuur, veenus, maa, marss, jupiter, saturn, uraan, neptuun):");
    if (scanf("%31s", P) != 1)
    {
        puts("input error");
        return 1;
    }
    X = -1;
    for (i = 0; table[i].multiplier > 0; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(table[i].name, P) == 0)
        {
            X = table[i].multiplier*K;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Your weight on the planet %.2s would be %.2f kilograms\n",P,X);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Well, I can't really understand the last part of the code (for (i = 0...). Can you explain it to me.

Comment: It searches for element that has the name read, and when it is found, do the calculation with the multiplier associated to the element and finish searching.

Comment: Just one little improvement could be done - when an incorrect planet name has been entered